# Combine views. Between forms and native code.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have one absolute layout with a button, slider and one image as a background.

When I load the page I render it in each platform and add a UICollectionView in ios.

The problem is that the UICollectionView is always at front and I cannot see the button and the slider. If bring UICollectionView to back is goes behind the image.

How can combine the views?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the frame of the CollectionView so that it doesn't cover the entire screen?

Comment: I need that the  UICollectionView cover the entire screen. But I also need that the button and slider goes to the front.